# Why does TextView cannot display formatted text referred from android resources?

Tags: java, android, android-resources, string.xml

I am trying to display a text that i set in `TextView`. I have already assigned a string in `strings.xml` with the name **operator_mixed**

**Strings.xml**

```
<string name="operator_mixed">%d  %s %d  %s %d</string>
```

And in my initialize.java file i tried to refer to this string, but it doesn't display anything.However when i try to display text without any formatting it kinda works ,but i know concatenating strings in textview is not preferable.

**Initialize.java**

```
textview.setText(getString(R.string.operator_mixed, a1, operator1, a2, operator2, a3));
```

Where a1, a2, a3 are integers and operator1, operator2 are strings.

Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just need to pass a Context like this:

```
textview.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.operator_mixed, a1, operator1, a2, operator2, a3))
```

here c is the context of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
<string name="operator_mixed">%d  %s %d  %s %d</string>
```

```
textview.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.operator_mixed),a1,operator1,a2,operator2,a3)));
```

You have to use `String.format()`

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to check the line is executed ? This code is supposed to work. Maybe the line is simply not executed ?

Comment: yeah i have checked, it works . when i try to setText like this   **textview.setText(getString(R.string.operator_mixed))**  it works ,it displays the text in operator_mixed in strings.xml directly.but it deosnt work when i tried to do like above suggested answer @Arthur Attout  .

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code in my app.

string.xml: (Same as yours)

```
<string name="operator_mixed">%d  %s %d  %s %d</string>
```

MyActivity.java

```
int a1 = 10;
int a2 = 20;
int a3 = 30;
String operator1 = "Operator 1";
String operator2 = "Operator 2";

my_txt_title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.operator_mixed, a1, operator1, a2, operator2, a3));
```

It's working fine.

[image]

Comment: I know that is the correct syntax and i know it should work ,bt i assume  there is some problem with the android studio syncing files or something like that.Am sure the code is perfect as it displays the string  directly inserted into it .Thank you for the help I will look on to it.Somehow it displays exact text in strings.xml when i do this .  **textview.setText(R.string.operator_mixed)**